# How to refresh graph after change of parameter value in Scilab application?

Tags: scilab

I tried to make a simple application which solves ode for given starting value `y_0`.

For example we can have:

> dy/dt = -2ty

Using some tutorials (scilab site and a youtube tutorial) I arrive at current version:

```
function dy = f(t,y)
    dy = -2*t*y;
endfunction

function updatePlot()
clf(right)
y0 = get(y0CONTROL,"value");
t0 = 0;
t = 0:0.1:10
solution = ode(y0,t0,t,f);
plot(solution, right)

endfunction

gui = figure();
gui.visible = "on";
gui.immediate_drawing = "on";

left = uicontrol(gui,...
'style','frame',...
'layout','gridbag',...
'constraints', createConstraints('border', 'left',))

right = uicontrol(gui,...
'style','frame',...
'layout','border',...
'constraints', createConstraints('border', 'center'))

y0CONTROL = uicontrol(left, ...
'style','slider', ...
'max', 10, ...
'min', -10, ...
'value',-1,...
'callback', 'updatePlot')

updatePlot()
```

As one can see I attempted to use `clf(right)` to clear previous graph and `plot(solution,right)` to plot in now presumably empty `right` frame.

And yet this attempt fails - old lines stay on the graph after movement of the slider.

Please tell me how to correct this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a more smooth solution is just to change the curve data:

```
   function updatePlot()
     y0CONTROL;
     y0 = y0CONTROL.value
     curve=y0CONTROL.user_data
     t0 = 0;
     t = 0:0.1:10
     solution = ode(y0,t0,t,f);
     if curve==[] then //first call
       plot(t,solution)
       curve=gce().children(1); //the handle on the curve
       y0CONTROL.user_data=curve;
     else //other calls
       ax=gca();
       ax.data_bounds(:,2)=[min(solution);max(solution)];
       curve.data(:,2)=solution.';
     end
   endfunction

   gui = figure();
   ax=gca();
   gui.visible = "on";
   gui.immediate_drawing = "on";
   y0CONTROL = uicontrol(gui, ...
   'style','slider', ...
   'position',[20 20 100 20],...                      
   'max', 10, ...
   'min', -10, ...
   'value',-1,...
   'callback', 'updatePlot()',...
   'user_data',[])
   ax.background=-2;

   updatePlot()
```

Comment: Sadly, in this version graph remains invisible. Unless you are using different version (I have 6.0.1) there seems to be an error:/

Comment: Nevermind, I see now - I didn't add definition of `f` to your code.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that refreshing effect can be achieved by substituting
`clf(right)`
with

```
current_axes = gca()
delete(current_axes)
```

[This](http://mailinglists.scilab.org/Refresh-plot-from-Slider-td4031131.html) was useful.